# Mysql Workbensh ER diagram

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have Doliwamp installed, and I want to create an ER diagram in MySQL Workbench. When I connect to my database, I encounter this error message. Despite clicking on "Continue anyway" and following the steps to create a diagram (Database >> Reverse Engineer >> Connect to my database, etc.), the option "Place objects on diagram" remains unchecked.

Can anyone help me, please? please

I have put the image of the error message and the uncheked option.
here]https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXM3p.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/UerI7.png